# unable to access local web server over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, webserver, wifi-configuration

I'm using a Huawei wifi dongle to create a small wifi network in my house. I mostly just need a network to access my webserver on network devices and occasionally share files

**Problem:** Webserver can only be accessed by network if the dongle is plugged into my main PC (where the webserver is installed).

The webserver can not be accessed if i plug the dongle into a power outlet

Is there a way to fix this?

Dongle model: HUAWEI EC315

Comment: That's big task.  This approach is mostly based on issue of routing and ip assinging (DHCP).  I accomplished on my end with 3 servers where I can access to all of them via my Xperia and vice versa.  DD-WRT is what made it possible.  Maybe shift your focus on the router itself, not the dongle.  DD-WRT will pick up the dongle and does the configuring on its own and connect it to all devices on network.

Comment: Ok, so the EC315 is essentially a 3G mobile hotspot, similar to the MiFi.  But you are not trying to use it as a means to connect to the internet - just as a way to create a wifi network.  But the EC315 could be blocking traffic between wifi clients, because its main purpose is to provide up to 5 wifi clients with 3G internet access, so it may actually segregate wifi clients as a "security feature".  Try this simple test - join the wifi network with both your server and another computer (laptop maybe).  Find out each computer's IP address and use `ping` to test connectivity. Report back here.